# How to access namespace which is part of different project?

Tags: assemblies, namespaces, c#-2.0

I have two C#.net projects project 1 and project 2 (names changed) in single solution. I am using Visual Studio 2005. I have added reference of project 2 in project 1 by right clicking and choosing 'Add Reference'. Both projects are of 'Application' project type not Class library type. I have some classes in project 2 which I want to access in project 1. After adding reference I tried to use import namespace of project 2 in project 1 but I guess its not available. Visual studio Intelisense is not showing me the desired namespace. 
Can anyone please suggest about how to access namespace and classes across multiple projects?

EDIT :- Is it because there are different assemblies for both the projects?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the classes you want to access are public. So suppose you have the following class in Project 2:

```
namespace Project2
{
    public class Foo { }
}
```

In Project 1 after you've referenced Project 2 you can use this class:

```
namespace Project1
{
    using Project2;

    public class Bar
    {
        public Bar()
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for answer. I have checked those classes and they are public, but I am not able to add namespace itself so not sure whether classes will be accessible or not.

Comment: Thanks for example. I'll remember to provide example from next time. So as shown in example, I am not able to access 'Project2' namespace itself in project1.

Comment: @shekhar, what do you mean you are not able to add namespace? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not getting any error. What I mean is, intellisense is not listing 'Project2' when I type 'using'

Answer (score 0):

`Import` is a Visual Basic.NET term. In C# you would use `using`.